# PHP if elseif statement on array applies first true statement to all array items

Tags: php, arrays, function, if-statement, woocommerce

I have a PHP function I've been working on all day.

I've gotten to this point, and have hit a brick wall.

```
add_filter( 'wcv_commission_rate', 'my_wcv_commission_rate', 10, 4 );
function my_wcv_commission_rate( $commission, $product_id, $product_price, $order ) {

global $woocommerce;

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $_categoryid = $term->name;

        if($_categoryid == 'T-shirts'){
            $per_item_addition  = 12;

        }
        elseif($_categoryid == 'Canvas'){
            $per_item_addition  = 10;

        }
        else{

        }
    }
}
$commission = $product_price - $per_item_addition;  
return $commission; 
}
```

### The function is is supposed to do this:

1. identify each item in the shopping cart
2. get their product category names
3. store the array of term names from step #2 in `$_categoryid`
4. pass each array item through the `if elseif` statements **individually**
5. subtract each item's `$per_item_addition` amount from `$product_price`

### The function so far does

1 successfully

2 successfully

3 successfully(I used `echo $_categoryid` and every products category popped up the correct amount of times. )

4 is where everything stops working. if I have three items in my array which are T-shirt Canvas Canvas the if elseif statement will use 12 for the Canvas as well. Also, when there are duplicate array items they are treated as one item so the function resolves as T-shirts = `$product_price - 12` and Canvas = `($product_price * 2) -12`.

So if I have T-shirts Canvas Canvas in my array it will pick up 12 as `$per_item_addition` and then use it once on T-shirts and once on Canvas(as opposed to twice)

5 behaves fine as long as there are no identical array items

So concentrating on #4 and #5 I really need to get the array to resolve each item individually So the T-shirts item will pass through the if elseif statement pick up 12 as `$per_item_addition` and then subtract that number from `$product_price` then start over at Canvas pass it through the if elseif statement and assign 12 to the variable `$per_item_addition` and finally subtract it from it's `$product_price`, and again for each array item afterwards.

I have no idea what's going wrong. I also tried using Switch statements, it behaves exactly the same, though.

Edit:

I tried Sean's suggestion and changed the loop to:

```
 foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $_categoryid = $term->name;

        if($_categoryid == 'T-shirts'){
            $per_item_addition  = 12;
            $commission = $product_price - $per_item_addition;
            return $commission; 
        }
        elseif($_categoryid == 'Canvas'){
            $per_item_addition  = 10;
            $commission = $product_price - $per_item_addition;
            return $commission; 
        }
        else{

        }
    }
```

and:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $_categoryid = $term->name;

        if($_categoryid == 'T-shirts'){
            $per_item_addition  = 12;
            $commission = $product_price - $per_item_addition;

        }
        elseif($_categoryid == 'Canvas'){
            $per_item_addition  = 10;
            $commission = $product_price - $per_item_addition;

        }
        else{

        }
return $commission;
    }
```

none had any behavioral changes :/

Comment: your `$commission = $product_price - $per_item_addition;` is outside your loop, and since you set `$per_item_addition` inside the loop, each iteration of the loop will overwrite the previous value before you ever use it. If you want to use the correct `$per_item_addition` you need to place it in your loop.

Comment: Also if this is a running total you may wanna do something like  `$commission += $product_price - 12;` inside those if and ifelse statements. Cut your code down a bit ;)

Comment: @Sean I placed the items inside the loop like you specified, and it had absolutely no change :/

Comment: probably because you are overwriting `$commission` now in each loop. You have `$commission` as a function parameter, but never use that value. Why is that?

Comment: @Sean How do I prevent overwriting $commission? I figured the very last code block would not overwright it. Also, I'm not sure, I removed it, but does a non used parameter hurt the function?

Comment: Well, I removed $commission from the function parameters and the math is now waaaay off. So I guess it does serve a purpose.

Comment: a non used parameter does not 'hurt the function', other than to confuse anyone who doesn't know your code as they wonder why you define it but never use it.

Comment: Did you remove it from both the function declaration AND the function call? If only from the first and not the second, then it could throw everything off as now your other params are in the wrong place/order

Comment: I am still not entirely sure what your end result would be. So with your example of `T-shirts, Canvas, Canvas`, then your result would basically be  `$product_price - 12 - 10 - 10`. correct?

Comment: Nope, I'm using `add_filter( 'wcv_commission_rate', 'my_wcv_commission_rate', 10, 4 );` to overwright `wcv_commission_rate` in the plugin with my own function. `wcv_commission_rate` took 4 parameters, I guess that means I should use '' in place of the parameter

Comment: @sean yes, essentially. and right now all it does is `$product_price - 12 - 12` I have no idea why x.x